# Beginner question: extrusion is square-shaped instead of rounded. (Blender Guru's donut tutorial)

Tags: extrude

I'm following Blender Guru's donut tutorial, and I'm stuck at the part where you use extrude to create dribbles: https://youtu.be/R1isb0x4zYw?t=630

I added a subsurf modifier before trying to extrude. If I add another subsurf modifier, it doesn't fix the problem. Proportional editing was on before I hit E. My dribbles are still square shaped. When I left-click to finish extruding, in the "Extrude Region and Move" pop-up that appears at the bottom of the screen, the "Proportional Editing" box is unchecked, but it's still toggled on in the toolbar at the top of the screen. If I check the box, the dribble becomes rounded, but the new face collapses. I feel like I must be doing something wrong, because it didn't look like too many people had a problem with this step. What should I be doing to make dribbles that are rounded instead of square?

Edit: The shape of the dribble is still square in object mode.

[image: Square dribble after attempting to extrude]
[image: Extruded face collapses after ticking proportional editing in extrude pop-up]

Comment: First off - don't worry - proportional edinting has no effect on extrude operations - only moving, scaling, etc.... I think you just need to switch back to _Object Mode_ to see it properly - the _rounding_ effect is a result of the subsurf modifier which tries to take an "average" between sets of faces or points and draws an interpolated curve to create the mesh "inbetween" - this is seen best in object mode. Case in point - a cube with a subdivision surface is a sphere - so rounding can still be achieved with "squarelike" faces.

Comment: Additionally, however, I'll give the same advice I always give regarding the donut tutorial - _Every_ time you make a mistake, or things don't turn out right, close the program (no saving) and start over from the _very beginning_. It might seem like a pain, but the repetition will make you much faster and more comfortable with blender's systems. By the end, you'll be able to do the entire donut scene in less than 10 mins with no guidance.

Comment: The shape of the extruded face is still square in object mode. I redid the tutorial until the point that I got stuck and I ran into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck at this point as well.
It was simply missing the step of adding the *Subdivision Surface* back again after applying it to doubling the vertices.

I see that you don't have the *Subdivision Surface* modifier so its possibly that too.